# Finding the smallest sum of sequares (SS) for indoor positioning

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am developing an android app for indoor positioning, I already stored wifi fingerprints in a table **tbl_rssi** that includes the following columns:

1. _id (the id of each fingerprint - This also a FK for tbl_reference_points._id)
2. MAC (the MAC address for access points that could be read in each fingerprint)
3. signal (the signal of each access point)

I have also another table **tbl_reference_points** that contains:

1. _id (PK for each one of the 20 reference points).
2. floorNum (in the building)
3. buildingNum (the number of building)

Before working on my database:

- I declare WifiManager and use startScan() to read the access points and their signals in every predetermined reference point.
- I store the result of scanning in a `List<ScanResult>`.

Let's say I have stored 10 mac addresses for each one of 20 reference points () in tbl_rssi. To determine the location of the user (That is at which one of the 20 reference points he is), I need to do the following steps:

1. Retrieving the records with same mac addresses that I am getting from the List of ScanResults. Here, I guess a dynamic query should be created.
2. Find the difference between prestored signal and the signal that we have read in the list for each record in previous step for all 20 reference points.
3. Calculating the square for each difference separately.
4. For each one of the 20 reference points, the summation of (square of differences) should be calculated.
5. Finding the smallest number and this is the required reference point.

I believe I need to create a dynamic SQL query and I could do that for the first step. But I need help to do the calculations in the subsequent steps because I am new to SQL queries. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide details about the tables where the data is stored?  Any attempts that you have made will also help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited my post and added the other table in the database. I tried to use new ArrayList to keep the results of calculations but I couldn't keep track for the reference point ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do computations in SQL, you need to have the scanning results in the database.
Create a table like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ScanResults(MAC, signal);
```

and fill it.

For one particular reference point, you can compute the signal strength differences for each MAC by joining the `ScanResults` and the `tbl_rssi` tables:

```
SELECT tbl_rssi.MAC,
       tbl_rssi.signal - ScanResults.signal
FROM tbl_rssi JOIN ScanResults ON tbl_rssi.MAC = ScanResults.MAC
WHERE tbl_rssi._id = ?
```

Computing the sum of the squares is simply done with an aggregate function:

```
SELECT SUM((tbl_rssi.signal - ScanResults.signal) * 
           (tbl_rssi.signal - ScanResults.signal))
FROM tbl_rssi JOIN ScanResults ON tbl_rssi.MAC = ScanResults.MAC
WHERE tbl_rssi._id = ?
```

To compute that sum for each reference point instead of one particular reference point, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT tbl_rssi._id,
       SUM((tbl_rssi.signal - ScanResults.signal) * 
           (tbl_rssi.signal - ScanResults.signal))
FROM tbl_rssi JOIN ScanResults ON tbl_rssi.MAC = ScanResults.MAC
GROUP BY tbl_rssi._id
```

To get the reference point with the smallest value, order the result by the computed value column, and then take only the first record:

```
SELECT tbl_rssi._id,
       SUM((tbl_rssi.signal - ScanResults.signal) * 
           (tbl_rssi.signal - ScanResults.signal))
FROM tbl_rssi JOIN ScanResults ON tbl_rssi.MAC = ScanResults.MAC
GROUP BY tbl_rssi._id
ORDER BY 2
LIMIT 1
```